# Relationship between 2 models in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two models- Order and Expense. The expense is a crud list respective to the particular Order. How can I make such a relationship between these two models?

**models.py - Order**

```
class Order(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="order",blank=True,null=True)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    event_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=False)
    expenses = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
```

**Models.py - Expense**

```
class ProjectExpense(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="project_expense",null=True,blank=True)
    order_id = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    exp = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    exp_desc = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.exp
```

I tried assigning the field Order ID with the current Order. But how will I able to pass the current Order.

Comment: Have you tried this? order_id = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE). As you add expenses you will need to update the expenses field in Order

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Yeah, but it will give a list of order, that the end-user explicitly have to mention the order. I just want it to add dynamically.

Comment: How do you want to link it dynamically? You will need to select the order from a list somewhere

Comment: I'm really sorry I didn't provide the necessary details.I'll be clear this time, Order list contains all the orders. If I click on a particular Order, it will be redirected to a page, which contains complete details about that particular order. In that page, I have a button to add expenses of that particular order. When I click add expenses, those list of expenses must be added respective to that particular order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for providing me the answers! The feature I'm looking at is GenericForeignKey. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vLJo0fQpiU) tutorial helped me understand it.

The working of Expenses associated with the respective Order, is way similar to the Comments and Post like in blogs.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you need a ManyToOne Relationship: One Order can have multiple expenses?

For that you can remove the expenses property from the Order model.
And you need to modify the order_id property of the ProjectExpense model like this (as @Lambo already commented):

```
order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When you are querying the Order model the related Expenses will be included if you ask for them and vice versa.

The Objects are created as following in the backend:

new Order:

```
# input contains the data received from frontend
Order.objects.create(user_id=input.user_id,
                     client_name=input.client_name,
                     event_name=input.event_name,
                     contact=input.contact,
                     event_date=input.event_date)
```

new Expense:

```
# input contains expense details received from frontend
ProjectExpense.objects.create(user_id=input.user_id,
                              order_id=input.order_id,
                              exp=input.exp,
                              exp_desc=input.exp_desc,
                              amount=input.amount)
```

It is important that you write `order_id=` although the property in the model itself is called `order`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm sure it will help. But I guess, ManytoOne relationship gives a list of Orders IDs.  And the user has to select one each time they add an expense. whenever I open an Order Details, and add expense, all the expense I add must be respective to the particular order.

Comment: @akajash I'm not sure if I got what your expected behaviour is. You want to add a new expense to a single order so that this expense only belongs to the one specific order? For that you need to give the backend the expense details and the order_id. How the user chooses the order doesn't matter as long as only one id gets transferred to the backend. And I guess that it would be in the scope of another question as we don't know anything about your frontend. Not sure about that.

Comment: I'm really sorry I didn't provide the necessary details.I'll be clear this time, Order list contains all the orders. If I click on a particular Order, it will be redirected to a page, which contains complete details about that particular order. In that page, I have a button to add expenses of that particular order. When I click add expenses, those list of expenses must be added respective to that particular order.

Comment: Then I guess you know the id of the order as you are on the page for that specific order. This id needs to be transferred to the backend and the new expenses will be linked to the order.

Comment: exactly! But I don't know how to pass the current order ID automatically, without having to explicitly type the order ID. But I've got an Idea, The order ID is contained in the Page's URL, Can I fetch it through that?
The URL : localhost:8000/order/22/details/

Comment: if you're working with plain http that should work. but I don't know a lot about that

Comment: Thanks! I'll research on it!